# Console.app: HALS_OverloadMessage.cpp:445:LogPageFaultRecord

Tags: audio, xcode, hal, console.app

guys.

Does someone know what does this exception means?

I've developed a game in Buildbox 3 and exported it to Xcode.
When pluged in my iPhone 6 to Mac and ran game via Xcode - game crashing after few minutes of playing and I see in Console.app this:

mediaserverd (CoreAudio), Subsystem: com.apple.coreaudio, Category: AudioHAL_Server:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy1hu.png)

Also in Xcode there is an error: 
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbad0bad1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpvWj.png)

Does anyone know how to fix HALS_OverloadMessage.cpp:445:LogPageFaultRecord?

Answer (score 0):

HALS_OverloadMessage is an error from the audio system. Either something in coreaudio has a design bug or performance issue, or some other process is snooping away too much CPU at moments that are critical for coreaudio to perform properly. Most pople seem to tend to the 2nd cause but it is not clear what that other process is. Maybe there are even multiple...